# stderr not getting redirected to a file in Solaris shellscript

Tags: shell, solaris, stderr

I have written a shell script (on Solaris platform, if that matters), and want to redirect all the output and error of a ZFS command to a file. But when I execute the shell script, the error message is still shown on the prompt instead of redirecting to a file. Following is the shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh        

`zfs <command>` 2>&1 | tee file.txt   #doesn't work    
##`zfs <command>` >> output.txt 2>&1  #doesn't work
```

This creates a output.txt of size 0 bytes and error message is displayed on the command prompt.

```
 sudo ./testShell.sh    
cannot load key for '/tank/test1': incorrect key.
```

Any inputs, please?

Comment: Try: `zfs key -l -a 2>&1 | tee file.txt`  (no backquotes).

Comment: It worked after removing the backquotes..Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This does not do what one might expect:

```
`zfs <command>` 2>&1 | tee file.txt
```

The above command executes `zfs <command>`, collects the standard out from that command and treats that output as if it were a command and tries to execute it.

In all likelihood, you just want `zfs <command>` executed and its output redirected.  In that case:

```
zfs <command> 2>&1 | tee file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!